# Complete list of MediaPlayer error codes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm implementing a `MediaPlayer`. Everything goes smoothly BUT each time I encounter a new error it can be very hard to find its meaning. The official doc is lacking in that area, so a website like stack overflow is the only solution and this time even this does not work (error (1;-107) btw).

So is there a centralized point where I can find the list of all the MediaPlayer error codes ? I can't find it in the official documentation, and it would be tremendously helpful to quickly diagnose new errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just go through these [pvmf return codes](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h) and the [complete explanation of each error](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/doc/pvmf_return_codes.pdf).

Comment: For what it's worth, the links above do not reference error -107 that @Teovald was looking for.

Comment: 1,-2147483648
Couldn't find for the second parameter
this issue came when pressing home on live streaming

Comment: I found 1004 here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java I think the issue is that some of these error codes come from the C++ player and some of them come from the media player wrapper itself.

Answer (score 15):

There are several places where the errors are defined.

- In theory, everything should be defined in [MediaPlayer.java](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)
- but some codes are just defined in C, and not accessible in the Java land, see [MediaErrors.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h)
- and also [pvmf_return_codes.h](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h)

Comment: Second link (MediaErrors.h) is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Your can find them in the source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h). And compare your error number with every constants given there

Comment: What about Error (1,-22)?

Comment: what about (1, 23)? And why would this show up due to http -> https change