# AndroidMediaPlayer error code -1005

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-5.0-lollipop

I implemented a video activity based on `MediaPlayer` and with a `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener`.

In Android-L, the `onError` is invoked with:

> onError(mp, what=1, extra=-1005)

What does code -1005 mean?

Edit: I looked in the error code definition in [`pvmf_return_codes.h`](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h) suggested by [Complete list of MediaPlayer error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13047116/94363)

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378273/1777090) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1005 means "connection lost".

The MediaPlayer class has not been updated to contain the relevant constant yet.

Comment: Can you help me by posting mediaplayer error codes here?

Answer (score 2):

-1005 is "connection lost", see this [webpage](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-release/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h) for a complete list of codes.

Comment: Providing the webpage should be reason enough to make this the accepted answer.